# Are BV functions "almost continuous"?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be the open cube $(0, 1)^n$, $n \geq 2$, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Denote by $A$ the set of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\Omega$ with measure $1$.

For any $f \in L^\infty (\Omega)$, define $Of(x) \in L^\infty (\Omega)$ by

$Of(x) := \inf_{S \in A} \lim_{d \rightarrow 0} \sup_{y, z \in S \cap B_d (x)} |f(y) - f(z)|.$

By Lusin’s theorem, given any such $f$, we may find for any $e > 0$, a compact $K \subset \Omega$ with $\mu(K) > 1 - e$ such that $f|_K$ is continuous.

Given $f \in L^\infty (\Omega)$ and $e$ in $(0, 1)$, define the number $S_f (e)$ by

$S_f (e) := \inf_{L} \frac{1}{\mu(L)} \int_{L} Of(x) dx$,

where the infimum is taken over all open sets $L$ with $\mu(L) < e$ such that $f|_{\Omega \setminus L}$ is continuous.

Is it true that for all $f \in BV(\Omega) \cap L^\infty (\Omega)$,

$\lim_{e \to 0} S_f (e) = 0$?

Comment: My conjecture would be that $Of = 0$ a.e. and thus that trivially $S_f(e) = 0$. Of course, on the jump set of $f$, $Of$ should correspond to the height of the jumps, but that set is too small to make a difference. In 1D this idea is easily turned into a proof by noting that $|f(y)-f(z)| \leq \|Df\|([y,z])$, but in higher dimensions I am not entirely sure how. I fear there might be a reason why one usually uses approximate continuity instead.

Comment: I think this is not true for n >= 2, since a Sobolev (and hence BV) function can be essentially unbounded on every open set (and hence essentially discontinuous everywhere). In 1D it is indeed true that BV functions have Of = 0 a.e.

Comment: Oh dear, I guess that answers my question negatively since (if what I said is accurate) I can just force Of to be uniformly bounded below..

Comment: If you have solved it yourself, you can post an answer so that the question does not appear unanswered.